# Add line for echarts legend icon

Tags: javascript, legend, echarts

I want to realize echart legend icon with line

I want to implement a circle icon with horizontal lines as show in fig. 1.
[fig. 1 circle icon with lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNWPZ.png)

Friends online say line is the default, but my echart has no line. My echart version is "echarts": "^5.4.0", and echarts options configuration is as follow:

```js
dataVolumeOptions: {
        legend: {
          show: true,
          icon: 'circle',
          bottom: '0',
          width: "auto", 
          height: "auto",
          orient: "vertical",
          align: "auto",
          itemWidth: 20,
          itemHeight: 10,
          itemGap: 10,
          data: [{
            name: "data-size",
            itemStyle: {
              color: "#FFFFFF",
              borderColor: '#1088FF',
              borderWidth: 2,
            },
            textStyle: {
              color: "#000",
              fontSize: 14
            },
          }]
        },
        xAxis: {
          data: ['2023-4-25 9:46:00', '2023-4-25 9:46:00', '2023-4-25 9:46:00', '2023-4-25 9:46:00', '2023-4-25 9:46:00']
        },
        yAxis: {},
        series: [
          {
            name: "data-size",
            type: 'line',
            label: {
              show: true,
              position: 'top',
              fontSize: 14
            },
            data: [10, 22, 28, 23, 19],
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: Changed your code and put an executable example, see if now I understand correctly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you need. I changed the code a lot, see if this is the result you want.

The legend icon was added, in this case with the name "Blue line". This icon is a standard feature of ECharts, running your original code it really doesn't show up.

Below is the updated code with the executable example.

```js
      var grafico = echarts.init(document.getElementById('grafico'));
      var dataVolumeOptions = {
  title: {
    text: 'test code'
  },
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis'
  },
  legend: {
    data: ['Blue line']
  },
  grid: {
    left: '3%',
    right: '4%',
    bottom: '3%',
    containLabel: true
  },
  toolbox: {
    feature: {
      saveAsImage: {}
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    boundaryGap: false,
    data: ['2023-4-25 9:46:00', '2023-4-25 9:46:00', '2023-4-25 9:46:00', '2023-4-25 9:46:00', '2023-4-25 9:46:00']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Blue line',
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'Total',
      data: [10, 22, 28, 23, 19]
    },
  ]
};
      grafico.setOption(dataVolumeOptions);
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Exemplo ECharts</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.4/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="grafico" style="width: 600px; height: 200px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried what you suggested and it didn't work. 

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks again. I runned your code supplied, it works. I am find the key point that causes the difference between my origin code and yours.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason that my lengend icon with no line. itemWidth is too low and itemStyle.color cannot be '#FFFFFF'. The correct setting should be:

```
legend: {
      show: true,
      icon: 'circle',
      bottom: '0',
      width: "auto", 
      height: "auto",
      orient: "vertical",
      align: "auto",
      itemWidth: 30, // correct this
      itemHeight: 10,
      itemGap: 10,
      data: [{
        name: "data-size",
        itemStyle: {
          color: "#1088FF", // correct this
          borderColor: '#1088FF',
          borderWidth: 2,
        },
        textStyle: {
          color: "#000",
          fontSize: 14
        },
      }]
    },
```